# GWT exited with status 1

Tags: gwt

My problem is that I have an error when running gwt maven plugin.
In particular mvn package and mvn gwt:devmode fails with status code 1.
I don't understand what the error is, so I copy and paste here my maven output.
Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Here below an extract from dependency section of my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${version.gwt}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${version.gwt}</version>
        </dependency>

... more dependencies here

</dependencies>
```

Here below there is the plugin configuration I use in my project

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc-8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <moduleName>iason.ifrs9.web.client.Ifrs9EntryPoint</moduleName>
        <moduleShortName>Ifrs9Module</moduleShortName>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use a different source language for java compilation -->
        <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
        <!-- Compiler configuration -->
        <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <!-- DevMode configuration -->
        <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
        <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
        <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
        <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>Ifrs9Home.html</startupUrl>
        </startupUrls>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

We have the following output running mvn -X package:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.410 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-17T10:12:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-8:compile (default) on project Ifrs9-Web: GWT exited with status 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-8:compile (default) on project Ifrs9-Web: GWT exited with status
 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT exited with status 1
    at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.CommandLine.execute (CommandLine.java:50)
    at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.CompileMojo.execute (CompileMojo.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Try adding `<logLevel>TRACE</logLevel>` to the gwt-maven-plugin configurattion and search inside the output for ERROR

Comment: I've tried it but I obtained the same output.

Comment: Well, it should not change the result of the  compiliation, but gives you more informations about the GWT compilation.  I assume, you have some errors during the GWT compile and logLevel TRACE should make them visibie. But keep in mind, that IDE limits the output, so you have to increase the output size to see them all.

Comment: Can you add more of the log, specifically above the `[INFO] BUILD FAILURE` line? That is where GWT would have logged anything interesting, like what @ElHoss was asking for.

Comment: I've the following lines before [INFO] BUILD FAILURE -> [INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]    [ERROR] Module has no entry points defined

Comment: Well, that is a fatal error - with no entrypoints, it is like running a Java application with no `main()`. You should add a `<entry-point class="..." />` tag pointing at your `EntryPoint` implementation.

Comment: I've the "entry-point" tag in my module.gwt.xml, but I still have the error.

Comment: After a mvn clean I've the following error when I callmvn package: [INFO] Loading inherited module 'iason.ifrs9.web.client.Ifrs9EntryPoint'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Unable to find 'iason/ifrs9/web/client/Ifrs9EntryPoint.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?